# How to change cursor css property when start to scroll and again change cursor property when stop to scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular

I try to change cursor property in angular function.
In my question is when i start scroll the web page now the cursor will change pointer and when i stop scroll now the cursor will be change default.
I try **window.pageYOffset** property. But it's output is cursor will be change to pointer but when i stop the scroll again the cursor will be pointer.

Help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3f3qzq?file=src/app/app.component.css) You can use hostlistener for this

```
  class="casa";
  private timeout: number;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) // for window scroll events
  onScroll(event) {
    this.class="hand";
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.class = "casa";
    }, 300);
  }
```

and u can use custom class css properties

```
.hand{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.casa{
  cursor:default ;}
```

and give this event to html

```
<div class="{{class}}"(scroll)="onScroll($event)" </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var timer = null;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
document.body.style.cursor = 'all-scroll';
if(timer !== null) {
    clearTimeout(timer);        
}
timer = setTimeout(function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
}, 150);
}, false);
```

- Detect an event of scrolling then change the global cursor.
- Set timeout so that if the user has stopped scrolling set it back to normal.